# How to create this alphabetical pattern in Python

Tags: python

I want to create this alphabetical pattern:

```
A
B C
D E
B C
A
```

So far I have done this:

```
n = 4
ch = 65

for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        if j == 0 or j == 1:
            print(chr(ch), end =" ")
            ch += 1
    print()

for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    for j in range(0, i):
        if j == 0 or j == 1:
            ch -= 1
            print(chr(ch), end=" ")
    print()
```

But the output is something like this: (For n =4)

```
A 
B C 
D E 
F G 
G F 
E D 
C B 
A
```

This does not mirror as per my expectation.
I have got this problem in the comment section of one of my blog and I can't solve it: [Alphabetical patterns in Python](https://www.codespeedy.com/python-program-to-print-alphabetical-pattern/)

Comment: can you post how should the output look for `n=3` or `n=5`?

Comment: For 5 it will goes upto "H I"

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved as follows (code comments explain the steps):

```py
# A given value of N will produce (2 * N - 1) rows, of which the first N rows
# will be unique and the remaining (N - 1) rows will be mirrored
num_rows = 3
# The code of the starting character
start = 65

# Produce N unique rows: first row has one character, all others have two
rows = [chr(start)] + [f"{chr(start + 2 * i + 1)} {chr(start + 2 * i + 2)}"
                       for i in range(num_rows - 1)] if num_rows > 0 else []
# Produce (N - 1) mirrored rows by reversing everything but the last row,
# join with line breaks, then print
print("\n".join(rows + rows[-2::-1]))
```

Or slightly differently:

```py
# A given value of N will produce (2 * N - 1) rows, of which the first N rows
# will be unique and the remaining (N - 1) rows will be mirrored
num_rows = 3
# The code of the starting character
start = 65

# Produce all necessary characters (one for the first row, two for all others)
chars = [chr(i) for i in range(start, start + 2 * num_rows - 1)]
# Produce N unique rows: pop 1st character for 1st row, zip others into pairs
rows = ([chars.pop(0)] + [f"{a} {b}" for a, b in zip(chars[::2], chars[1::2])]
        if chars else [])
# Produce (N - 1) mirrored rows by reversing everything but the last row,
# join with line breaks, then print
print("\n".join(rows + rows[-2::-1]))
```

In both cases, `num_rows` corresponds to the question's `n` (at least I guess so) and `start` corresponds to the question's `ch`.